# echo $output['subject'] - css property

Tags: php, html, css, echo

I have a problem with:

`echo $output['subject']` - I want add to this echo property in CSS

**PHP code**

```
 mysql_connect('localhost','****','****');
 mysql_select_db('***');
 $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC');
 while($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

{

echo $output['subject'].'<br />';
echo $output['news'].'<br / >';
echo date('D-M-Y', $output['date']).'<br / >';
echo 'Posted by '.$output['postedby'];
echo '<hr />'; 
}
```

How do I add to all echo CSS property? I've tried `<div>`, but it didn't work.

Comment: _I try but dont work._ You tried what???

Comment: I guess you need to look at adding some tags around those echo's I'll try and answer but your question isn't too clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
.subject {
    css: here
}
</style>
echo '<div class="subject">' . $output['subject'] . '</div><br />';
```

You need to include the CSS either in line on the div tag itself (or similar).... or use an ID or class.  Above I have used a class.

This could be useful: http://www.cssbasics.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam. And what is reason why a cant use external style.css?

Comment: No reason at all... you just need to load it in...

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

Comment: Yes i have <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" /> on head in .php but i add .subject to style.css and dont work.

Comment: Strange... when you open up the DOM in inspector tools... can you access the CSS file using its link?

Comment: In .php I have other div and external css works smoothly on this div

Answer (score 1):

This code may fulfil your requirement

```
<style>
   .class {
      property: <?php echo $output['subject']; ?>;
   }
</style>
```

Or

```
<div style="property: <?php echo $output['subject']; ?>;"></div>
```